# How much space do I need for lv_root?

Tags: arch-linux

I'm trying to install Arch Linux for the first time and I'm following a video for it. In the video I follow, the installer gives about 30 GB for the lv_root. Since he had about 500 GB it's normal but I'll just give 50 GB for arch Linux that means I can't give 30 GB. But how much space does it need? Can I just give about 3 GB and would that be enough? As far as I understand we can not use lv_root space for the storage like installing DE, WM, games, etc. Thanks in advance.

I'm installing with these commands btw.

```
 # fdisk -l
 # fdisk /dev/sda
 - p  
 - g 
 - n  
 - Last Sector = +500M  
 - t 
 - Partition type = 1
 - p  
 - n
 - press enter all until created
 - t 
 - press enter
 - Partition type = 30
 - p  
 - w 
 # mkfs.fat -F32 [dev/sda1]  
 # pvcreate --dataalignment 1m [/dev/sda2] 
 # vgcreate volgroup0 [/dev/sda2]  
 # lvcreate -L 30GB volgroup0 -n lv_root
 # lvcreate -l 100%FREE volgroup0 -n lv_home
 # modprobe dm_mod
 # vgscan
 # vgchange -ay
 # mkfs.ext4 /dev/volgroup0/lv_root
 # mount /dev/volgroup0/lv_root /mnt
 # mkfs.ext4 /dev/volgroup0/lv_home
 # mkdir /mnt/home
 # mount /dev/volgroup0/lv_home /mnt/home
 # mkdir /mnt/etc
 # genfstab -U -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

to check if everything's okay so far

```
 # cat /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Comment: 3GB definitely isn't enough. You can install games and anything else anywhere that you want. How much space you should allocate otherwise depends entirely on the purpose of the system.

Comment: If I give all the space to lv_root, can I also use that or just name it lv_home? And not create lv_root at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: In order for your system to function, you have to have filesystem at `/`.

Comment: if you are extremely space restricted, consider using one single filesystem instead of dividing it into partitions. but it's all up to your personal preference and requirements.